# hi i have a question on separating a network into 3 subnets

Tags: routing

The subnet is 192.168.53.0 how is this divided into 3 sub-nets? I am unsure as to how this should be done, i would really appreciate the help. Thanks

Comment: How many devices do you want to accommodate per subnet ? 
What is your overall intent ?

Comment: You might be able to answer your question by playing with a subnet calculator. http://www.subnet-calculator.com/

Comment: @stephenmuth I rejected your edit because the OP could still be referring to a network address.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

Any subnetting operation will always be based on a factor of two, because the binary number system is base 2. Therefore splitting up any network into specifically three equal sized parts won't ever be possible.

You *can* however split up 192.168.53.0 into **four** equal-sized subnets:

```
192.168.53.0/26    to  192.168.53.63/26
192.168.53.64/26   to  192.168.53.127/26
192.168.53.128/26  to  192.168.53.191/26
192.168.53.192/26  to  192.168.53.255/26
```

Comment: You're right of course, but I don't know that the asker strictly meant "how is this divided into 3 sub-nets *of equal size*". I can see how it's easy to infer that though.

Comment: OP didn't say "at least 3", they said 3, which I infer as no more than or no less than 3. Two points - it doesn't change the answer to the question, and it's obviously a homework question anyway. :-)